# Get currently active input field. Chrome content script. Script injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

### What I want to do:

How can I get the value of the input field the user is currently typing into? 
I am injecting JavaScript via a Chrome Content Script into the visited website.

### What i have already tried:

I was trying `alert($('.lastSelected').attr('id'));` and `alert('document.activeElement.value: ' + document.activeElement.value);` with no success. Both approaches deliver `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the `:focus` selector. It will select all elements that have a focus.

https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

If a user is typing, that means one of three keyboard events are going on. Either `keypress`, `keydown`, or `keyup`. To get the id of the focused element, we can use the `prop` method.

```js
$("input").on("keydown", function() {
      alert($(":focus").prop("id"));
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
setInterval(function () {
  var focus = document.querySelector(":focus");
  document.querySelector("output").textContent = focus ? focus.id : "none";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input type=text id="a" />
<input type=text id="b" />
<output></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a piece of the code it is a bit complicated to answer accurately.
Are you getting anything in our code? Since you are using Chrome Content Script you can be block by CORS problems. Another thing to think about it, the field that you are try to get value is in the HTML DOM or was created by another piece of Javascript? 
In the Chrome Content Script documentation it mention that you will not have access to variables and objects that came from other JS codes:

Execution environment
Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page. It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse: JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any variables defined by content scripts.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Also, it can be a typo... so a piece of your code could complement your question.